# Oracle 11g Compression

Tags: oracle11g

How do I know whether Oracle 11g Basic compression does not compress and uncompress in normal DML operation.
Does it only valid for direct path insert?

Answer (score 0):

I spike through internet and I found a very good article on compression(the document is for 10g compression), which holds true for 11g compression as well.

References

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/oem/11g-compression-198295.html

[10g compression](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/twp-data-compression-10gr2-0505-128172.pdf)

What I got here is Oracle 11g basic compression does the compression if you choose the direct path i.e /*+append*/, create as select etc. If normal insert, delete happens it does not compress the data again.

Comment: I found the solution from the above mentioned links.